# Migration Issues from MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.1 version

Tags: marketing-cloud

Got the trouble during updating MarketingCloudSDK version to 8.0.1 How to call the same method MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_isReady() using SFMCSdk. Also, do you have any documentation which describes all included method in library after updating? I found this https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html section but it doesn't describe all methods. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Also can't find analogue method to MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_getSDKState() in the new version of sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. I am currently working on updating the documentation, however let me try to help You really quick here now.

If You are trying to see if the SDK was initialized I would advise You to use a completion handler - please find an example in the LearningApp, right [here](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/blob/spm/LearningApp/LearningApp/AppDelegate.swift#L35-L71).

Otherwise, for the Mobile Push Module, please check for the status in a following way:

```
    if (SFMCSdk.mp.getStatus() == .operational) {
        // ...
    }
```

You are free to also check for other statuses ("cancelled", "disabled", "failed", "inactive", "initializing", "operational").

Most of the methods You know are matching the old ones, with a small change of removing the sfmc_ prefix, such as: *sfmc_setDeviceToken = setDeviceToken*, etc. Hope that helps! Feel free to reach out with any further questions.